# Resize image automatically when the screen size decrease

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using an image as a background of my  and it fits perfectly.
When I try to resize the screen (Mobile/tablet size) the image stays in the back and not get shrink like the screen - not become responsive.
I would like to change this effect and make it responsive and become smaller as to the size screen.

See attachments.
[image: Full Width]
[image: Small Width]

HTML:

```
<!-- Header -->
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h3>The</h3>
        <br>
        <a id="show-panel" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
/* Header */
.header {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../img/coffee.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Don't set `width` or `height` in your CSS, instead add `background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;background-position:center;`

Comment: What are the advantages of this method ?

Comment: There are some good answers here. Why not accept one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try using position absolute on the header div and setting the margins to always cover the entire area. I did an example here based off your code. https://codepen.io/morganfens/pen/NjJBJB

```
.header {
background: url(../img/coffee.jpg);
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
right:0;
left:0;
background-repeat:no repeat;
background-size:cover;
color: #ffffff;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching up the width and height to use vw and vh instead of %.  Also instead of using scroll as the position on your background-image property, use fixed. 
I tried it out in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/46f6kz0c/).

```
.header {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/food) no-repeat center center fixed;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I've changed it in my app but then in the 'Inspection', if I am changing the view to mobile/tablet view it becomes smaller and not fit to screen as in %.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this CSS code:

```
html { 
  background: url(img.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

From here: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Remember to do some research before asking a question! A quick search of "css full background image" on google gives you loads of good answers.

Comment: Hi, James I did my friend otherwise I wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: Did do some research you mean?

Comment: Because you're using 'no-repeat center center scroll' and I'm using 'no-repeat center center fixed'.